# PyQt5 - How to draw a dot on mouse click position?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I am trying to draw a dot on my main window, but the dot is not shown.

I've tried bounding `mousePressEvent` to `paintEvent`, but it didn't work as well. Here's current version of my code(which is not working too). Also I tried place a point with `drawPoint` method and it didn't work too.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, uic


class GUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print(e.pos())
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
        qp.drawEllipse(e.pos().x(), e.pos().y(), 10, 10)
        qp.end()
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I know that `mousePressEvent` is working since I get coords of the click.

I am okay to change methods of dot-placing or type of dots to place, but it should have customizable color and size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only draw within the `paintEvent` method, and this paint does not save memory so if you want to graph several points you must store them in some container, for example using `QPolygon`.

`paintEvent()` is called every time you call `update()` or `repaint()`, for example it is called every time it is resized, the window is moved, etc.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, uic


class GUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.show()
        self.points = QtGui.QPolygon()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.points << e.pos()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 5)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setBrush(brush)
        for i in range(self.points.count()):
            qp.drawEllipse(self.points.point(i), 5, 5)
        # or 
        # qp.drawPoints(self.points)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot. But if I have like 10,000 points, won't it be a little heavy on system to draw them all each time I update the view?

Comment: You should try to encourage users to use the search box than post answer to questions that have been asked again and again.

Comment: @notEmissary you should draw to an image to use as cache instead, and in the paint event simply pain the image onto the widget. This way you only do heavy painting when you need to change the representation.