# How to implement mouseMoveEvent on QPainter?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter

I have the same question with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699848/pyqt5-how-to-draw-a-dot-on-mouse-click-position) and I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49700136/15870976) to that question very helpful.

I have tried to run the provided code in the answer and it worked.

**The Code included with the provided [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49700136/15870976):**

```
import random
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.rect = QtCore.QRect()
        self.drag_position = QtCore.QPoint()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        if True:
            self.rect = QtCore.QRect(
                QtCore.QPoint(*random.sample(range(200), 2)), QtCore.QSize(100, 100)
            )
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if not self.rect.isNull():
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawEllipse(self.rect)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(1)
        if (
            2 * QtGui.QVector2D(event.pos() - self.rect.center()).length()
            < self.rect.width()
        ):
            self.drag_position = event.pos() - self.rect.topLeft()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(2)
        if not self.drag_position.isNull():
            self.rect.moveTopLeft(event.pos() - self.drag_position)
            self.update()
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print(3)
        self.drag_position = QtCore.QPoint()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Rect = Window()
    Rect.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**My Question:**

How can I move these "points" when dragging them. My first thought is subclassing the `QPainter` and tweaking inside that class the events but when I read the docs, I found no method where I can move the "points". I'm really stuck here right now and I can't find the correct implementation for this.

Comment: I believe you're misunderstanding what QPainter is: it's a class that just performs drawing operation. It doesn't "store" anything, nor can interact with user input like mouse events: it's like a "sketch artist", you give them a canvas (the widget) and tell them what to draw. If you want to "move points", you have to store their data in some way, so that you can access it and modify it, and eventually draw it (which usually happens after calling `update()`).

Comment: @musicamante - Ahhh, After reading some notes and docs, I finally understand what QPainter is. As what you've said I need to put those "points" on a `QRect` then add its position to a List. Just one thing not clear to me is how can I know if a `QRect` is clicked ?

Comment: If you're going to check it in any mouse event handler, use `if event.pos() in someRect:`. Note that if you use PySide (which is a bit more strict) it doesn't implement the `__contains__` *magic method* (`if x in y` corresponds to `y.__contains__(x)`), so you need to use the [base implementation of QRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#contains): `if someRect.contains(event.pos()):`. For any other case that doesn't involve direct mouse events, you need to map the *current* cursor position to local coordinates: `pos = self.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos())`

Comment: To clarify what I wrote in my first comment: it's good practice to *not* reuse a QPainter after painting has completed, as the [docs also suggests](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#details): "Remember to destroy the QPainter object after drawing", so you shouldn't "store" anything in it anyway (and doing it with class attributes would not be a good idea, unless you ***really*** know what you're doing). There are very few, specific cases for which a QPainter could be "kept" and eventually reused (but I didn't directly need any in my experience), but for general usage it's a basic "*don't*".

Comment: @musicamante - Thank You for the Guidance! I'll try to follow and remember that. I'll try to implement this to the example above to see if it works. Thank You!

Comment: @musicamante - I've tried to implement that and it worked. Thank You! Just one last question is, Is it the correct implementation and is it efficient enough for a decent computer to run?

Comment: Please avoid editing the question with a *possibly* working answer, as it makes your whole post confusing. Instead, if it *does* work for you, post it as an answer (using the "Post your answer" link), and eventually specify that you're not completely sure if it's valid or not (and that you're the original author), *then* notify about it in the comments of the question and any *other* answer that you might have used as a source concept for yours. Separating questions and answers is *very* important, as it dramatically improves understanding for other users that could face a similar issue.

Comment: Note: I rolled back your question to the previous status to avoid confusion to other users (remember, StackOverflow is not a discussion forum! Questions are important for everybody, even for people that would find out and read your questions years from now: they *must* be able to understand it without any "thread context"). You can read the review history through the `edited ...` link on the bottom of the question in case you need to check what you've previously written, and eventually use that to create your own answer as you should (and remember that greetings are unnecessary!).

Comment: Sorry, and I will try to do that and will never do that again.

Answer (score -2):

I've tried to implement what @musicamante said in the comments about using `if event.pos() in someRect:` to the code included in the question and I end up with this code below.

**Usage:** A dot will appear when you click anywhere in the widget. You can move the dots by clicking stop and dragging the points.

**Implementation:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class GUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.stop = False
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.stop_)
        self.selected_item_index = None
        self.there_is_selected = False
        self.list_ = [] # list of points
        self.show()

    def stop_(self):
        if self.stop:
            self.stop = False
        if not self.stop:
            self.stop = True

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.stop: 
            self.rect = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(event.x() + 5, event.y() + 5), QtCore.QPoint(event.x() - 5, event.y() - 5))
            self.list_.append(self.rect)
            print(self.list_)
            #self.points << e.pos()
            self.update()
        elif self.stop:
            index = -1 # I set -1 so the first iteration in the for loop will be equal to 0
            for item in self.list_:
                index += 1
                if event.pos() in item:
                    print("there is selected")
                    self.selected_item_index = index
                    self.there_is_selected = True
                    break
                else:
                    self.selected_item_index = None
                    self.there_is_selected = False
        print(f"---- There is selected : {self.there_is_selected} in the index : {self.selected_item_index}")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.there_is_selected:
            self.list_[self.selected_item_index] = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(event.x() + 5, event.y() + 5), QtCore.QPoint(event.x() - 5, event.y() - 5))
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 3)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setBrush(brush)
        for i in self.list_:
            qp.drawEllipse(i)
        # or 
        # qp.drawPoints(self.points)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit:** Fixed the crash at start

The implementation above is working just fine but I'm still not sure and also curious if it's the proper implementation. To be honest, I'm also not sure if this will work on decent computers because I'm not sure if it's the proper implementation in the first place.